# How can we change data from base64 to localhost url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, imageurl

Firstly There is a yield that returns like this.

```
<figure class=\"image\"><img src=\"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGg //F12 network data
```

I want this data to register as localhost url from controller. I need a little change but I don't know what to do. In the MyUploadAdapter function, this url keeps the localhost url returned from the controller(this.url). what change do I need to make

```
 src=\"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGg...
```

return data as

```
src="https://localhost:5001/..."
```

and record?
Below is ckeditor's MyUploadAdapter function

```
 class MyUploadAdapter
 {
  constructor(loader) {
  // The file loader instance to use during the upload.
  this.loader = loader;
  this.url = '/tr/UnitType/DocUploadImage';
  }
            
//upload() {
//    return this.loader.file.then(file => new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
//        this._initRequest();
//        this._initListeners(resolve, reject, file);
//        this._sendRequest(file);
//    }));
//}

upload() {
var reader = new FileReader();
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
reader.addEventListener('load', () => {
resolve({ default: reader.result });
});

reader.addEventListener('error', err => {
reject(err);
});
reader.addEventListener('abort', () => {
reject();
});

this.loader.file.then(file => {
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
this._initRequest();
this._sendRequest(file);
});
})
}
// Aborts the upload process.
abort() {
if (this.xhr) {
this.xhr.abort();
}
}

_initRequest() {
const xhr = this.xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open('POST', this.url, true);
xhr.responseType = 'json';
}

// Initializes XMLHttpRequest listeners.
_initListeners(resolve, reject, file) {
const xhr = this.xhr;
const loader = this.loader;
const genericErrorText = `Couldn't upload file: ${file.name}.`;

xhr.addEventListener('error', () => reject(genericErrorText));
xhr.addEventListener('abort', () => reject());
xhr.addEventListener('load', () => {
const response = xhr.response;

if (!response || response.error) {
 return reject(response && response.error ? response.error.message : 
 genericErrorText);
}
resolve({
default: response.url
});
});

if (xhr.upload) {
xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', evt => {
if (evt.lengthComputable) {
loader.uploadTotal = evt.total;
loader.uploaded = evt.loaded;
}
});
}
}

_sendRequest(file) {
const data = new FormData();

data.append('upload', file);

this.xhr.send(data);
}
}

function MyCustomUploadAdapterPlugin(editor) {           
editor.plugins.get('FileRepository').createUploadAdapter = (loader) => {
return new MyUploadAdapter(loader);
};
}
      
// Class definition
var myeditor;
var KTCkeditorDocument = function () {
// Private functions

var demos = function () {

DecoupledEditor
.create(document.querySelector('#p_Ack')
,{
extraPlugins: [MyCustomUploadAdapterPlugin],
})
.then(p_Ack => {
const toolbarContainer = document.querySelector('#kt-ckeditor-3-toolbar');

                        toolbarContainer.appendChild(p_Ack.ui.view.toolbar.element);
myeditor = p_Ack;

})                
}

return {
// public functions
init: function () {
demos();
}
            };
        }();


        // Initialization
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            KTCkeditorDocument.init();

        });
```

Comment: this.loader.file.then(file => {
reader.readAsDataURL(file);

Comment: How do I add the url and not the file here?

Comment: What function should I call instead of FileReader and readAsDataURL in the upload function. How should I put this url? Is my question understandable?

Comment: resolve({
                        default: response.url
                    });

Comment: is the problem here?